# Error: Intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Error: My app is not launch and the intent filter is highlighted (this element is not allowed here).

Am I missing something and causing a mistake?

I've been trying to get an animated splash screen recently, which is why the intent filter might be an issue.

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.saul.eventpromotionapp">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"/>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="com.package.name.HomeActivity"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    />
    <activity android:name=".Splashscreen" />
    <activity android:name=".ContactActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity" >
        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you've copied is how your code looks, you're not using the xml tag correctly. You have:

```
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity"/>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="com.package.name.HomeActivity"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    />
```

If you notice, you're closing the activity tag right after declaring the name. notice the `/` in the first line. You need to delete that and it'll be fine. That way `intent-filter` will be a part of your `activity` tag which will close with the last `/>` tag.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error sadly ''intent element-filter is not allowed here". Also the top application is highlighted with "App is not index-able by google search. Consider adding at least one Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent filter."

Comment: `<activity android:name=".HomeActivity">`


Sorry, struggling to post code in comments, I have just removed the forward slash on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Your Manifest File.........

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.saul.eventpromotionapp">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="com.package.name.HomeActivity"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
     </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Splashscreen" />
    <activity android:name=".ContactActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity" >
        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```